# Modify Process (not services) Level Permissions via command line (Windows) - to make process interminable by non admin user

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, process-explorer

**Goal:**

On my PC, there is a background script (Process A) that runs on startup with Administrator Level Permissions on the Standard Level Account (Account X). I would like to use this script, with it's elevated permissions to modify the *process-level permissions* on a process (Process B) that is run by Account X on startup.

The goal is to make Process B interminable by Account X, whilst still being initiated by Account X.

**Background:**

This is easily achievable with [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), but this is a GUI program. There is some material online regarding changing permissions via command line, but these are for services, not for processes.

Specifically, I need to add Deny Permissions on Terminate Process, and Change Permissions to Account X for Process B.

**Summary:**

- Process A is started up on login (into Account X) via Task Scheduler running under an Administrator Account
- Process B is started up by Account X
- Account X is a standard level account
- I can use Process Explorer to manually add the Deny Permissions I am describing, but I want Process A to do it itself (perhaps by command line).

Comment: Is the real problem that you're trying to make Process B unterminable by the user?

Comment: Yes, I've been submerged in the problem too long! I've edited the question in response. The key problem is that Process B still has to be initiated by Account X, as when I try and initiate Process B using an administrator account, it doesn't initialise properly.

Comment: I don't think your approach is feasible. But if Process B is restartable, you could start two of them, where each one checks for the other and restarts it if killed. That will will make it unkillable, unless the user knows the `taskkill` command.

Comment: The user may know the taskkill command, and needs to control other processes that are not run with elevated permission (Process B would ideally be run under an administrator account, but it refuses to initialise properly when this is done)

Answer (score 0):

A program running with Administrator permissions can modify a process ACL
to remove PROCESS_TERMINATE permission.

An example written in C++ found in
[this post](https://sinister.ly/Thread-Unkillable-process):

```
static const bool ProtectProcess()
{
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS denyAccess = {0};
    DWORD dwAccessPermissions = GENERIC_WRITE|PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS|WRITE_DAC|DELETE|WRITE_OWNER|READ_CONTROL;
    BuildExplicitAccessWithName( &denyAccess, _T("CURRENT_USER"), dwAccessPermissions, DENY_ACCESS, NO_INHERITANCE );
    PACL pTempDacl = NULL;
    DWORD dwErr = 0;
    dwErr = SetEntriesInAcl( 1, &denyAccess, NULL, &pTempDacl );
    // check dwErr...
    dwErr = SetSecurityInfo( hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, pTempDacl, NULL );
    // check dwErr...
    LocalFree( pTempDacl );
    CloseHandle( hProcess );
    return dwErr == ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

More questions about this code should rather be asked on
StackOverflow.